# Dates and POSIXct

Tags: r

I read a file with the function

```
site_wind <- read.delim(import,header=F,sep="\t",skip=nline,quote="\"")
```

In the first column I have dates and times in the form:

```
01/05/2011 0:10 where "day-month-year hour:min"
```

I want to convert site_wind$V1 to class POSIXct and POSIXlt but when I do it:

```
as.POSIXct(site_wind$V1,"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M",TZ="GMT")
```

and I get:

```
"0026-01-20 GMT"
```

I have tried some alternatives, but I don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5):

You need literal `/` as the delimiter in the dates. In the `format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M"` part you are using literal `-` as the data separator, which doesn't match the date example you showed. I think you want

```
as.POSIXct(as.character(site_wind$V1), format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", tz="GMT")
```

Note that the argument is `tz` not `TZ` - R was silently ignoring that in your original call.

Comment: I think you meant to put `format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"` in your code block (to process dates of the form `01/05/2011 0:10`), right?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Yep copy-paste fail on my part. I have edited accordingly.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Can I ask a question? I did the same but mine did not work: I have a vector "StartDate" with dates and time for instance in 01Feb1991 00:00 format. I did as.POSIXct(as.character(bio$StartDate), format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") but I got NAs as result.

Comment: @Rusuer9000 There are no literal `/` in your input date so why did you include them in the `format` string? That'd be your problem. (By literal, I mean real `/` in the date string.)